# get_browser() function is echoing "default browser"

Tags: php

I want to write code that detects user's browser and echoes the name of the browser out.

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo 'your browser is '.$agent.'<br><br><hr>';
$browser = get_browser(null,true);
print_r($browser);
echo '<br>';
$browser = $browser['browser'];
echo $browser;
```

but I keep getting "default browser" instead of the real browser's name like chrome,IE,etc.

Comment: Why do you pass `null` as a first argument? What is the `$agent` value?

Comment: according to the tutorial I watched, the tutor said you can either pass null or the $_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]. I did according to him by passing null but my result was different.

Comment: if you pass it explicitly - the result become more obvious. So: 1. Use the explicitly specified UA, 2. provide what you currently have there

Comment: what do you mean by UA, because anytime I run the current code,it gives me the array of the browser details and in browser name,it writes "default browser"

Answer (score 0):

You should read manual for get_browser function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

**by looking up the browser's information in the browscap.ini file**

and

> In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on your system.
>   browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, but you may find an up-to-date » php_browscap.ini file here.
>   While browscap.ini contains information on many browsers, it relies on user updates to keep the database current. The format of the file is fairly self-explanatory.

Link to browsecap.ini file is in manual page.